# What would cause.....?

Tags: discussion

Right now I have a noise coming from my car when I get 50-60 mph. If I had to guess what the problem is, its that I need to rotate and balance my tires, but before proceeding with that theory, I want to confirm that is in fact the problem.

My current situation has made me ponder if you can ask questions such as "What are the tell tale signs of needing to rotate and balance my tires?". My thinking being that it might give the less experienced people (such as myself) a few things to check to confirm our suspicions before spending a bunch of money trying to fix the wrong problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem asking

> What are the tell tale signs of needing to rotate and balance my tires?

However I think you will get a better answer about what is actually wrong with your car by asking a more specific question detailing the symptoms of the problem. Something like the first paragraph of your question.

Comment: Especially since the tire problem could be a thrown wheel weight.  That's something that you can actually see (i.e., it should be there and it isn't).